# Yii2 hasMany without link fields

Tags: activerecord, yii2

User model has follow relation:

```
public function getWorkload() : ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasMany(ScheduleWorkload::className(), ['staff_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Find method:

```
$staffs = User::find()
            ->alias('u')
            ->joinWith(['workload as uw' => function($q) {
                $q->select(['uw.staff_id', 'uw.date', 'uw.time_ranges']);
            }], true)
            ->select([
                'u.id',
                'CONCAT(u.first_name, \' \', u.last_name) as name',
                'u.first_name',
                'u.last_name',
                'u.undelivered_messages',
            ])
            ->where(['u.is_staff' => 1])
            ->asArray()
            ->all()
          ;
```

I need get data without uw.staff_id in result set? Is it possible without post-processing?

UPDATE:
Result set that I have
[image]

I need "workload" as array parameter but do not use post-processing and just exclude "staff_id" from result set.

Raw sql:

```
SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`undelivered_messages` 
FROM `user` `u` 
LEFT JOIN `schedule_workload` `uw` ON `u`.`id` = `uw`.`staff_id` 
WHERE `u`.`is_staff`=1
```

Comment: and what result set do you have now? as i can see the variable `$staffs` is of type `ActiveQuery`. What is result of `$staffs->createCommand()->rawSql`?

Comment: I update post. Please look on update section.

$staffs is array. I forgot include ->asArray()
            ->all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do in Yii without any post-processing because `ActiveQuery` will search for foreign key in nested query result to build nested arrays for joined relation.

The most convenient way for you is to use `ArrayHelper`:

```
$staffs = User::find()
    ->alias('u')
    ->joinWith(['workload')
    ->where(['u.is_staff' => 1])
    ->all();

return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::toArray($staffs, [
    User::className() => [
        'id', 
        'first_name', 
        'last_name', 
        'name' => function ($user) {
            return $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name
        },
        'undelivered_messages',
        'workload',
    ],
    ScheduleWorkload::className() => [
        'date',
        'time_ranges',
        'comment'
    ]
], true);
```

Comment: can you explain me how to implement this in my searchModel please ,  or where can i find documentation about it ?